# Integrate along a closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=z^n$ I want to show that $f$ integrate to 0 along every closed curve in $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ except when $n=-1$. This seem to be trivial but I am not sure if I missed anything can someone let me know? Thanks. I guess any closed curve $[p,q]\subset \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ and parametrize with $\gamma(t)=(1-t)p+tq$ and $\gamma:[0,1]\to [p,q]$. Then $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$ and by definition of complex integral we have $$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=(\gamma(1)-\gamma(0))\int^1_0(\gamma(t))^ndt=0$$
And I dont see why this do not hold for $n=-1$.

Thank you for our help

Comment: The definition of the integral along $\gamma$ is $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int\limits_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$.

Comment: @RemuX, a note on the side: For $n\notin\mathbb Z$, you will need the complex logarithm (or a branch thereof) for the definition of $z^n$, and this will therefore contain a branch cut.

Comment: If you use the correct expression for the integral, you will see that the integral boils down to $\int_0^1 1\,dt$ for $n=-1$.

Comment: @DominikS Thanks, I see I havent read about the complex logarithm definition yet. I will go read that.

Comment: @Jochen thank you , I fixed it.